# How can I map over the characters in a string in Io?

Tags: string, list, dictionary, io, sequence

When I try to map over a string, I get:

```
Exception: Sequence does not respond to 'map'
```

Apparently, Io does not implement a `map` method for sequences. So how can I convert a string sequence into a list of characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a string to a list in Io?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255123/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-list-in-io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Io doesn't currently have a Sequence asList method, but one can easily be added.

```
Range

s := "abc"

# From StackOverflow
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255123/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-list-in-io/4256258#4256258
Sequence asList := method(
    result := list()
    self foreach(x,
        result append(x)
    )
)

s asList map(c,
   "Char: #{c}" interpolate println
)
```

Output:

```
Char: a
Char: b
Char: c
```